# What is the probability distribution of arrival times in a distributed system?

Tags: probability-theory, distributed-systems, statistics

I'm going to *simulate* an *asynchronous distributed system*. In a distributed system, when a node sends a message, after $\Delta t$ seconds the message reaches to its destination.

**My Question:** What is the probability distribution of $\Delta t$s?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is this over the internet? What is the topology of the distributed system?

Comment: I don't think the answer is answerable from the information provided.  All we can say at this point is "it depends".  What kind of links are we talking about?  I'd expect this is a situation where you need to make measurements to assess what distribution is observed in practice.